# Backup iPad to SD card

Tags: ipad, backup, sd-card

I would like to never worry about losing any of my data while I'm traveling, away from an internet connection and at risk of losing or damaging my iPad.

Is there an app on Cydia or otherwise that will backup a complete 1-1 copy (or archive) of my iPad's files such that it can be easily restored and just as easily browsed on a PC to find a particular file?

Obviously the app should only copy files that have changed since last backup.

This is of course assuming I'm using the Camera Connection Kit with an SD card.